# How do I avoid duplication in a view result?

Tags: views, location

I want to list the states from the state/province field (handled by the Location module) in a content type. I used views, but it shows the same state name more than once.

I enabled distinct in the Views module, but it doesn't works. How can I avoid the same state name is shown more than once?

Current Result: Illinois, Georgia, Alabama, Illinois, Alabama, Alabama, Georgia.

I attached the screen shot of my view (I used table format and views group by module).

Expected Result : Illinois, Georgia, Alabama.

This is my views set up.

[image: screenshot]

This is what I'm getting from my view.

[image: screenshot]

I'm expecting this result no matter how many nodes have the same state; I want to display the state name only once.

[image: screenshot]

This is the table style I used, and views group by module.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If Views' `distinct` parameter doesn't work for your case, you can always use a `views_pre_render()` hook to do anything with the result before it is rendered.  Something along the lines of...

```
YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name=='NAMEOFVIEW') {

    // drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->result, TRUE) . '</pre>');

    $states_found=array();

    foreach($view->result as $delta => $row) {

      if (in_array($row->LOCATION_FIELD_NAME_VALUE, $states_found)) {
        unset($view->result[$delta]);
      } else {
        $states_found[]=$row->LOCATION_FIELD_NAME_VALUE;
      }

    }

  }

  // any other pre_render()ing here...

}
```

What this does is loop through the rows of your view result keeping track of what states have been found and unsetting any duplicates.  The commented out `dsm` at the beginning will help you figure out what `LOCATION_FIELD_NAME_VALUE` you need to use in your specific case.

Comment: @Jimajamma.I used this in my views.module but the $views doesn't retrive any values and its not working.Anyother solutions?

Comment: This code is meant to go in a module of your own creation. Just replace "YOURMODULE" with (for example) "statereducer", save the file as "statereducer.module", make a file called "statereducer.info" and put them both in a folder called "statereducer" in your modules folder. Copy another modules .info file, replacing where needed. Go to admin/build/modules and enable it.

Comment: Also, uncomment line 5 and change "NAMEOFVIEW" to the machine name of your view and "LOCATION_FIELD_NAME_VALUE" to that of the field as it appears in the output of drupal_set_message().

Comment: @Jimajamma & griz. Hi,I apologize to both of you.I used your code but it doesn't give me the result exactly what I expected.I repeats the state names because it gets the state name for each and every node.If I might not understood and followed your instructions correctly I apologize for that.Any way thanks for your post and support!.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get the state names(major condition is no matter how many nodes have the same location but it should retrive the state name only once)

```
<?php 
$var = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT province FROM  location");
          while($variable = db_fetch_array($var)){

            print $variable['province'].'<br/>';

          }
```

?>

Just used the select query in my page.tpl it displays the statename only once even one or more than one node has chosen the same state.